# OpenMaple Java Interface

Tags: java, linear-algebra, maple

I am trying to use OpenMaple with Java interface to simply turn a matrix into reduced row echelon form. Ultimately I want to find the inverse of a matrix. I am not sure how to take a 2-d array in my program and make it interact with engine objects.

Some basic examples are here.http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=OpenMaple/Java/Engine/evaluate

I basically want this: `t.evaluate( "with(LinearAlgebra): A:=<<2,4,8>|<8,2,4>|<4,8,2>>; ReducedRowEchelonForm(A);" );`

Problem 1: getting a 2-d matrix I made into that statement.
Problem 2: somehow making it output into another 2-d array as a result.

I don't know much about OpenMaple, therefore I come here. Thanks!

Comment: I can't answer your main question, but I want to warn you against using command "with" in any programmatic code. Use long-form procedure names like LinearAlgebra:-ReducedRowEchelonForm instead. "with" is only intended for interactive sessions.